# How do I open a directory in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans-8

I'm sure there must be a way to do such a common task, but I'm not finding it after googling around for awhile.  All I want to do is to open a panel that lists all the files in a specified directory.  I often work on directory trees of files that aren't in a NetBeans project.  So, just like the "Files" panel, but instead of files in a *project* I'm looking to specify the starting directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to explicitly do this with NetBeans as far as I know.

However, one possibility that may indirectly give you what you want is to add a version control plugin for Git or Subversion that happens to provide that functionality, but I am not aware of a specific plugin that would help.

One other approach I tried was to start up an app server in NetBeans and use the Embedded Webkit Browser (**Tools -> Options -> General -> Web Browser -> Embedded WebKit Browser**), and then supply a file url of a local directory (e.g. **file:///D:/temp** ) in that browser. Unfortunately, although that works fine in Firefox and Chrome, it doesn't seem to work in the browser NetBeans uses. Maybe there are configuration settings for that.

One other possibility is to create a dummy Java web project in NetBeans, and then add the directories you want to view in NetBeans to that project. To do that:

- Create a web Project (**File -> New Project -> Java Web -> Web Application**).
- Select the **Libraries** folder of that "throwaway" web project.
- Right-click and select **Add JAR/Folder...** from the popup menu.
- In the **Add JAR/Folder** window navigate the the desired directory and click **Open**.

Then you can use those directory(s) and their content as though they were normal project directories and files. See the screen shot below showing several local directories chosen randomly that I added to the project. You can also safely remove those local directories from the project (without deleting them from disk) by selecting the directory, right-clicking and selecting **Remove** from the popup menu.

[image: LocalFilesInProject]

Comment: A bit of a hack and it unfortunately explodes some of the subfolders out into dotted folders at higher levels, but it's quite workable!